# Как правильно: дня или дней?

Tags: числительные

Как правильно выбрать форму числа для существительного: *за 23 календарных **дня или дней**?*

Comment: "за 3 дня" или "за 3 дней"?

Comment: @Сибиряк  Зря минусуете вопрос...  С днями вроде бы всё понятно, а если речь идет о сутках. Например, если трое суток, то как подобрать  правильное сочетание для числа 23.  Для каждого случая есть правило, поэтому хорошо бы его найти и сослаться на него. Вот такой подход мне кажется корректным.  И почему это домашнее задание, тоже непонятно.  Может, автор просто составляет какой-нибудь текст

Comment: @Sharon если с днями все понятно, то непонятен смысл вашего комментария. Вопрос-то как раз о днях, а не сутках. А минус не за вопрос, а за бессмысленный заголовок.

Comment: И бессмысленные метки.

Comment: Участник первый раз зашел на сайт, всех правил не знает. Можно же отредактировать и название, и метки. Поэтому вас и просят: будьте дружелюбны! А правило простое: числительные два, три, четыре, а также СОСТАВНЫЕ числительные на два, три, четыре в И.п. и В.п управляют Р.п существительных в ед. числе: три дня, двадцать три дня. Но в остальных косвенных падежах используется мн. число: в течение трех дней, двадцати трех дней. А здесь, кстати, В.п. с предлогом, да еще прилагательное в форме мн. числа: за три календарных дня, за двадцать три календарных дня. Это тоже дополнительная неопределенность.

Comment: Серьёзно, чё накидали "закрыть"-то, да ещё и якобы за то, что домашнее задание. Очевидно же, что это не домашнее заданиме.

Comment: А метки-то почему бессмысленные?  В этой теме падежные окончания —  самая сложная вещь, так как управление  (в косвенных падежах) переходит в согласование.  Выбирается падеж и для оборота, и для существительного в составе оборота.

Comment: Под вашим напором я отозвал свой голос за закрытие, но на самом деле: если человек смог задать вопрос здесь, то уж найти ответ - еще легче. А метки были действительно несуразные:  *склонение фамилий, пунктуация*.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Я, конечно же, обратила внимание на ваше голосование. Метки я  видела уже исправленные, а насчет ответа, который легко найти, я  не поняла. Сравним два сочетания: 23 дня и 23 календарных дня. В первом случае ед.число выбирается по слуху как единственно возможное (3 дня - 23 дня), а во втором случае существительное контактирует с прилагательным, стоящим  в форме мн. числа. Вот что, как мне кажется, было причиной непонимания.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***за 23 календарных дня.***

Правило:

1. Числительные два, три, четыре, а также СОСТАВНЫЕ числительные на два, три, четыре в И.п. и В.п **управляют** Р.п существительных в ед. числе: *три дня, двадцать три дня*.

Но в остальных косвенных падежах используется мн. число: Р.п.: *в течение трех дней, в течение двадцати трех дней*, (П.п.): *о трех днях, о двадцати трех днях*.

2. Определение, выраженное прилагательным, ставится всегда в форме мн. числа: *за три **календарных** дня, за двадцать три **календарных** дня, в течение двадцати трех календарных дней.*